# Call oracle report from url with specific charset

Tags: oraclereports

I call report by using rwservlet.

I have unicode parameter and data was mess up when it used on report.

How can i specific charset to parameter that i send to report?
Is it possible to do that without configure on report server.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The best way of course is to configure rwservlet. did you tried to changing encode, before transferring parameters to report server?

Comment: I already tried to encode parameter value before sending but that not work after all. and I'dont have access to report server so i want to know if there another way to do this.

Comment: Did you tried to recompile report with different charset?